# Rotate inner rectangles anchoring on top-left considering size

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

So I have a rectangle R, anchored at its top-left. Inside the rectangle I have inner rectangles, each with an width and a height. I have an algorithm to rotate R by alpha degrees, and need to calculate the new top-left position of each inner rectangle, but those rectangles are not rotated.

I have this function which calculates the new top-left coordinate of an inner rectangle, but it does not work for inner rectangles of different sizes.

```js
static rotatePoint(x0, y0, xi, yi, degrees) {
        // Calculate the coordinates of the point relative to the top-left corner of the box
        let x = xi - x0;
        let y = yi - y0;
        
        const rad = degrees * (Math.PI/180);
        const cos_rad = Math.cos(rad);
        const sin_rad = Math.sin(rad);
    
        // Calculate the transformed coordinates after rotation
        let qx = x0 + cos_rad * x + sin_rad * y
        let qy = y0 + -sin_rad * x + cos_rad * y

        return { x: qx, y: qy };
    }
```

For example, the image below displays a formation at 0º, there are 5 inner rectangles, one of width and height ~2, and four of width and height ~1. The red dot represents the origin and it is constant.

[image]

Rotating the formation by 90º, I get the following:

[image]

Notice how the 2x2 rectangle's top-left coordinate is located where it should be if it had size 1x1. How could I adapt the function to correctly calculate to position of each inner rectangle considering its size?

Edit:
This is not plain Javascript, it is for foundry vtt, but since the problem is not related to to foundrt vtt itself, I feel like tagging it as such would make it unecessarily niche.

Inner rectangles actually start at a origin rect center, but it doesn't change the calculation as well. I'm changing some foundry specific properties, but here is a snippet which gives the same ouput as in froundy:

Edit2: I've replaced the snippet with a visual one.

```js
class Rect {
    static rotateUnit(origin, inner, direction) {
        const angle = origin.rotation + ((direction > 0) ? 45 : -45);
        const delta_angle = origin.rotation - angle;
        origin.rotation = angle
        const box_x = origin.x + (origin.width / 2);
        const box_y = origin.y + (origin.height / 2);
        
        for (var i of inner) {
            var new_pos = Rect.rotatePoint(box_x, box_y, 
                                            i.x,
                                            i.y,
                                            delta_angle);
            
            i.x = new_pos.x;
            i.y = new_pos.y;
        }
    }
    
  static rotatePoint(x0, y0, xi, yi, degrees) {
        // Calculate the coordinates of the point relative to the top-left corner of the box
        let x = xi - x0;
        let y = yi - y0;
        
        const rad = degrees * (Math.PI/180);
        const cos_rad = Math.cos(rad);
        const sin_rad = Math.sin(rad);
    
        // Calculate the transformed coordinates after rotation
        let qx = x0 + cos_rad * x + sin_rad * y
        let qy = y0 + -sin_rad * x + cos_rad * y

        return { x: qx, y: qy };
    }
    
    static printCoordinates(origin, inner, offset) {
        const ratio = 5
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      if (canvas.getContext) {
          var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
          ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
          ctx.fillRect(origin.x/ratio+offset/ratio, origin.y/ratio+offset/ratio, 70*origin.width/ratio, 70*origin.height/ratio);
          ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
          for (var i of inner) {
            ctx.fillRect(i.x/ratio+offset/ratio, i.y/ratio+offset/ratio, 70*i.width/ratio, 70*i.height/ratio);
          }
     }
    }
}

/* 
* SIZE (WIDTH AND HEIGHT) CORRELATES TO 
* PIXELS BY A CONSTANT OF 1:70
*/
const rect_origin = {
    rotation: 0,
  x: 2302.492125,
  y: 1700.492125,
  width: 0.9842500000000001,
  height: 0.9842500000000001
}
const inner = [
    {
    x: 2336,
    y: 1734,
    width: 1.9685000000000001,
    height: 1.9685000000000001
  },
  {
    x: 2336,
    y: 1872,
    width: 0.9842500000000001,
    height: 0.9842500000000001
  },
  {
    x: 2405,
    y: 1872,
    width: 0.9842500000000001,
    height: 0.9842500000000001
  },
  {
    x: 2336,
    y: 1941,
    width: 0.9842500000000001,
    height: 0.9842500000000001
  },
  {
    x: 2405,
    y: 1941,
    width: 0.9842500000000001,
    height: 0.9842500000000001
  }
]

Rect.printCoordinates(rect_origin, inner, -1500);
Rect.rotateUnit(rect_origin, inner, 1);
Rect.printCoordinates(rect_origin, inner, -1100);
Rect.rotateUnit(rect_origin, inner, 1);
Rect.printCoordinates(rect_origin, inner, -700);
Rect.rotateUnit(rect_origin, inner, 1);
Rect.printCoordinates(rect_origin, inner, -300);
Rect.rotateUnit(rect_origin, inner, 1);
Rect.printCoordinates(rect_origin, inner, 100);
Rect.rotateUnit(rect_origin, inner, 1);
Rect.printCoordinates(rect_origin, inner, 500);
Rect.rotateUnit(rect_origin, inner, 1);
Rect.printCoordinates(rect_origin, inner, 900);
Rect.rotateUnit(rect_origin, inner, 1);
Rect.printCoordinates(rect_origin, inner, 1300);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

Comment: I used your function passing it the relevant coordinates, and the output is correct. Please provide the minimal code with which we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: also note that since this is a plain JS question, you should be able to show this off as a runnable snippet in your post with just a smattering of canvas code

Comment: I added more information and a minimal snippet to display the results I'm getting with real data.

Comment: Note the position of the first (big) inner rectangle is ~2269, but it should be ~2199 to maintain the block formation.

Comment: What's the meaning of `box_x` and `box_y`, wasn't the rectangle supposed to be rotating around its top left corner? And if it's rotating around the center, the formula is not OK if the units of `x` and `y` are different from the units of `width` and `height`

Comment: It is. For foundry, my "top-left" is a token, a little square located at the top-left of the formation, This box(_x, _y) represents a rectangle around the top-left coordinate where the inner rectangles must rotate around. Its center is the top-left coordinate.